# Computing the G-twirling map

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators

I have been given the (singular) projector

$$
\mathcal{T}=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{is (\hat q_1+\hat q_2)}ds
$$

acting on a two particle Hilbert space. I want to compute its action on the position and momentum operators, i.e.

$$
\mathcal{T}\hat q_i\mathcal{T}^{-1}=?\\
\mathcal{T}\hat p_i\mathcal{T}^{-1}=?
$$

I know that as the $q$'s commute with the operator the position operator should be invariant under this map. But I then don't know how to show rigorously that

$$
\iint_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{i(s-t) (\hat q_1+\hat q_2)}dsdt = 1.
$$

I have the feeling that the momentum operator should be mapped to zero, but I cannot prove it. I am grateful for any help!

Comment: Do you want $T^\dagger$ or $T^{-1}$?  It is not obvious that $T$ is unitary.  Nor, indeed, that it is a projector.

Comment: You are right, then it should be $T^{-1}$. Do you know how to show if it is unitary? And indeed $T$ maps out of the physical Hilbert space into the space of functionals over $\mathcal{H}$ (loosely speaking). Do you know where operators on $\mathcal{H}$  get mapped to?

Comment: What does $G$ mean?